# How to print Unicode character bigger

Tags: java, user-interface, unicode, size, character

I've a problem with the Unicode.
I want to print the Unicode Character into a textfield, but at some characters i got the undefined symbol "".

```
int z = 2273;
char ch = (char) z;
txtText.setText(ch);
```

So I tried to do it with a JTable and it worked, but if I change the size of the text i get the undefined Symbol again.

That Worked:

```
int z = 2273;
char ch = (char) z;
table.setValueAt(ch, 0, 0);
```

But I wanted to see the character bigger and that worked not:

```
table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 80));
int z = 2273;
char ch = (char) z;
table.setValueAt(ch, 0, 0);
```

then I get again ""

My question is if the is any way to print the Unicode characters bigger

Thank you in advance for your answers. :D

PS: Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
table.setValueAt(Character.toString(ch), 0, 0);
```

Anyway, it will only display a square, because Tahoma font doesn't have the necessary glyphs for Unicode.